# Change Bottom Navigation Menu Item Text Color Android Studio

Tags: android, colors, navigation

How to change menu item text color in xml file

in drawable file the code looks like this file name: bottom_nav_menu_item_text_color.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:color= "@color/bottom_nav_menu_item_selected_color"
        android:state_checked="true"
        android:state_selected="true"/>

    <item
        android:color= "@color/bottom_nav_menu_item_unselected_color"
        />
</selector>
```

Bottom Navigation Menu Bar looks like this in activity_main.xml

```
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/bottom_nav_menu_bar"
                app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu_items"

                app:itemTextColor="@drawable/bottom_nav_menu_item_text_color"

                android:background="@color/white"
                />
```

Comment: Can you add more detail about current behaviour with SS or gif so we can know exact issue

Answer (score 0):

Can add more info with SS or gif about current behaviour so exact solution can be provided

But as you asked question about changing color of BottomNavigationView text change then you can use as mentioned below

tab_text_selector.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_selected="false" android:color="@color/unselectedTab" />
    <item android:state_selected="true" android:color="@color/selectedTab" />
    <item android:color="@color/unselectedTab" />
</selector>
```

In Activity xml

```
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/bottom_nav_menu_bar"
                app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu_items"

                app:itemTextColor="@drawable/tab_text_selector"

                android:background="@color/white"
                />
```